# why Self inside closure of function not returning the type of Extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

why `view` inside closure not returning the type of `UILabel`?

If any other solution is there please do let me know.

```
extension UIView {
     public func apply( _ action: ((_ view: Self) -> Void)?) {
        
     }
}

let label = UILabel()
label.apply { view in }
```

[image: screenShot]

Comment: It is. `UILabel` _is_ `Self`, in this context.

Comment: This question would be better if you actually had code inside the `apply` function of the extension. And it would also help if you showed some example code for how you would use `label.apply`.

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 2):

The `Self` points to the actual type and the actual type inside the `UIView` extension is the `UIView` itself!

What you are looking for is when you use `Self` inside a `protocol` definition which then points to the conforming entity's type.

To achieve what you are looking for, you need to use a protocol instead, like this:

```
protocol Applicable: AnyObject {
    associatedtype S = Self where S: Applicable
    func apply( _ action: ((_ view: S) -> Void)?)
}

extension Applicable {
    func apply( _ action: ((_ view: Self) -> Void)?) { action?(self) }
}

extension UIView: Applicable { }
```

then:

[image: Demo]

Comment: nice solution! +1. Though I would call the protocol "Applicable"

Comment: In our app we call it Applicand. Good implementation (and yet another nomenclature) here: https://github.com/devxoul/Then

Comment: @vikingosegundo better choice over `Appliable`. Thanks for the improvement